# Laravel Eloquent Query containing pivots and relations

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent

I want to make graphs based on values i get from my questionnaire. This is how my database looks like (Only showing the ones I need): 
questionnaires

```
id  
client_id
```

questionnaire_answers

```
id  
questionnaire_id    
questionnaire_question_id   
answer
```

questionnaire_questions

```
id  
question
```

What I want is basically get all the answers of question 1 (of all their questionnaires) from a specific client.
The idea is that they answer a question that is based on severity, so 1 - 5 basically.
I've tried this in the controller:

```php
$questionnaires = JsonResource::collection(
    Questionnaire::where('client_id', '=', 2)
    ->with([
        'clients', 
        'questionnaire_answers', 
        'questionnaire_answers.questionnaire_question', 
        'questionnaire_answers.questionnaire_question.questionnaire_question_type'
    ])
    ->get()
);

dd($questionnaires);
```

All relations work.

Comment: Does your current query work? If not, have you tried removing the `JsonResource` part?  `$questionnaires = Questionnaire::...get();`

Comment: Yes, that part works fine, I just needed someone to help me get to the result I wanted from that starting point, I;m gonna try the answer I've been given :)

Answer (score 1):

> What I want is basically get all the answers of question 1 (of all their questionnaires) from a specific client. The idea is that they answer a question that is based on severity, so 1 - 5 basically.

I'd redo the query so it starts from the `Question` model.

Assuming the following relationships:

- `Question` belongsToMany `Questionnaire` (using `Answer` as the pivot model)

```php
// Question model
public function questionnaires()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Questionnaire::class)
                ->withPivot('answer')
                ->as('answer')
                ->using(Answer::class);
}
```

```php
$client_id = ...;

$question = Question::query()
    ->whereHas('questionnaires', function ($questionnaire) use ($client_id) {
        $questionnaire->where('client_id', $client_id);
    })
    ->with([
        'questionnaires' => function ($questionnaire) use ($client_id) {
            $questionnaire->where('client_id', $client_id)
                          ->with('client');
        },
        'question_type',
    ])
    ->find(1);
```

```php
foreach ($question->questionnaires as $questionnaire) {
    $questionnaire->client->...        // client attributes
    $question->....                    // question attributes
    $questionnaire->answer->...        // answer attributes.
    $questionnaire->question_type->... // question_type attributes
}
```

Comment: I am gonna try this, I will let you know how far I get with it, thanks for the input!